# Change stroke or fill color in multiple files from folder

Tags: svg, adobe-illustrator

I have 9600 icons (SVG) in black. I need to change stroke and/or fill if exists in white and then again in blue. I will then have two packages once in white and once in blue. Is there a way to automate this in Adobe Illustrator without opening each single file.
Or maybe some other way?

I have tried with terminal like this but it didn't worked.

```
#/bin/sh
COLOR=#fff
sed -i -E 's/fill\="[^"]+"//g; s/stroke\="[^"]+"//g' *.svg
sed -i "s/<path/<path fill=\"$COLOR\" stroke=\"$COLOR\"/g" *.svg
sed -i "s/<rect/<rect fill=\"$COLOR\" stroke=\"$COLOR\"/g" *.svg
sed -i "s/<polygon/<polygon fill=\"$COLOR\" stroke=\"$COLOR\"/g" *.svg
sed -i "s/<circle/<circle fill=\"$COLOR\" stroke=\"$COLOR\"/g" *.svg
sed -i "s/<ellipse/<ellipse fill=\"$COLOR\" stroke=\"$COLOR\"/g" *.svg
sed -i "s/<polyline/<polyline fill=\"$COLOR\" stroke=\"$COLOR\"/g" *.svg
sed -i -E "s/stroke\:[^\;]+/stroke\:$COLOR/g" *.svg
sed -i -E "s/fill\:\#[0-9]+/fill\:$COLOR/g" *.svg
```

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: Hi, no not really. I also asked a question on Adobe Community https://community.adobe.com/t5/illustrator/change-stroke-and-or-fill-color-in-multiple-files-from-folder/m-p/11949132#M271012 it wasn't really helpful

Answer (score 0):

I believe it can be done both ways. Via RegExp text replacing and via Illustrator script. But Illustrator will open each single file, of course. And will save it. Is it a problem? You don't need to open the files manually.

As for text replacing there is a trick. As far as know in SVG if you want to draw black filled shape you don't need to add any style description to the shape. The black filled shape is a default shape. Here is an example of a black rectangle:

```
<rect x="100" y="100" width="100" height="100"/>
```

And here a is blue rectangle:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:#0000ff}
</style>
<rect x="100" y="100" width="100" height="100" class="st0"/>
```

So, the task to change any color to any color is quite simply unless the original color is not black. Since black filled shapes basically have no classes. You need to add some class to all shapes that have no class first. It demands more quirky RegExps.

Comment: Hi Yuri, thanks for your reply. Yes CSS is one option and it was also like that solved but I was hoping for some other options. For example as SVG is vector graphic some automation to do such operations should also be provided for AI files. Like automated batch option.